# ping between ipv6 and ipv4 networks

Tags: ipv6, ipv4, bgp, ospf

I have 2 networks (one ipv4 and one ipv6) , I used ospf as routing protocol for both networks.

I activate bgp between this 2 networks(R6 and R1) and now R6 can ping the full ipv6 network and R1 can ping the full ipv4 network.

Now I want r7 to ping r5 and vice versa. what should I do ? I try redistribute BGP into OSPF 1 and OSPF 2 but nothing changes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: IPv4 and IPv6 are two completely separate protocols, and an IPv4-only device can't directly communicate with an IPv6-only device, or vice versa. Would you expect an IPX-only device to be able to ping an IPv4 or IPv6 device?

Comment: Why not just enable IPv6 on the link between R6 and R7? Establishing connections from IPv6 only to IPv4 only hosts can be achieved through the use of NAT64. Doing it the other way is more complicated. I have developed software solutions capable of doing it, but if you are only a single link away from having IPv6 everywhere in your network, you are probably better off just upgrading the rest to support IPv6.